# NgRx ofType operator doesn't recognize action

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a bug which doesn't trigger any exception, but just doesn't work as supposed.
There is simle action f.e.

```
export const loadSth = createAction('[Data] Load data', props<{ id: string }>());
```

and then is effect f.e.

```
getSth$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(loadSth),
    concatMap()
    ...
    )
  )
});
```

When action is dispatched first time with one id, operator ofType pass this action, but second call of action (with other id) is blocked.
Any ideas how to handle it, to get full effect each time?

Comment: Is there a chance that the effect might throw errors? If so, are they caught?

Comment: In original there is a catchError, but even though there is no error without ofType operator, so effect is not suspicious in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think here the problem is with the `concatMap` operator, have you tried using `switchMap` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed description of this post yesterday (when I found solution, and realized that desc is misliding), because in first version I falsy "simplified" this case, assuming that operator doesn't matter for situation.
Latter on I've made some more tests, and realised that's because of this concatMap, and changed it to switchMap (and it started to work), and I described all of this in edit summary, thinking that it will be displayed :), but unfortunatelly there is no sign after that.. (I'm fresh here :)).
So you're right wit your suggestion.